# How to close the MAC application by menubar Quit Option

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I am trying to close the MAC application by pressing the Quit option from the menu bar. If I close by Quit button the application becomes unresponsive. The menu bar are generated by MAC, I just want to close the application properly if we click the Quit option. [image] .

My code is,

```
app = PageLoader()
app.show_frame(LoginPage)
app.geometry("1024x768+30+30")
app.iconbitmap(common.find_data_file("images/mediavalet.ico"))
def on_closing():
       app.destroy()
app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `import sys` and executing `sys.exit` when the quit is pressed. Include some code for better assistance

Comment: Added code, I don't know how to listen the quit button response.

Comment: Try replacing `app.destroy()` with `sys.exit()` and dont forget to `import sys`

Comment: @CoolCloud what I feel here is that the 'quit' menu item (which OP is talking about being generated by MAC itself) is some kind of system default which may not be changed with the code (however advanced menu options like cascade could work). I'd say to just create a menu of our own (which hopefully should override the system default) OR add item quit to the file menu (which is already there). Because we do not know what procedure does the current quit item tends to follow when clicked.

Comment: Try creating your own version of the menu bar and then add something akin to `root.configure(menu = my_menu)`.  That should overwrite the built-in menu.  Let me know if that doesn't work...I don't have a mac nearby to test